# Is there a way to catch what invoked value event listener

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, event-listener

Firebase data can be fetched by a single value event listener or a generalised value event listener. For my case I cannot use single value event listener. The problem is the listener gets triggered even when I do not want to. Let me explain the situation:

I have a number of users in my database who are from a particular locality. The firebase database contains the users as the root and their profile details, along with their location (in Latitude and longitude) as the child nodes.

Now as a simple case,  let's say a user wants to send a SOS for some emergency to other users located within a certain range. For that I perform some distance calculations between the user who is sending the SOS to all other users and make a list of other users who are present within a specified range. Then a notification is send to all these users. Here I use a value event listener to get the location details of the other users to compare with the location of the current user. My code runs as expected till this point. The value event listener is attached to the user node because I have to travel across the user details.

Problem occurs when a user changes his profile details. It evokes the value event listener and the code takes some garbage value of the location of a user sending an SOS. As a result although there is no actual SOS sent, a notification is getting sent.

Hope this explains the problem. I am not being able to provide the code as I am traveling and typing the code from my mobile. Can provide the code in some hours if it is necessary to guide on the problem.

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote??

Comment: Your event listener is attached to a high level node in your db hierarchy , try to design your database that you will only listen to event that occur in a low level nodes

Comment: Even if I add the listener let's say on the lower level, let's say at the location. If any particular user updates his location on the database, the SOS notification gets activated as the data is changing

Comment: You need to denormalize your data and set up a structure where you are only listening on nodes that have data you want listened to and reacted to. If a user updates his location *and is within the radius* you want an event to occur, right? I think your structure is causing issues but without code, a better description of the issue and what your Firebase structure looks like we won't be much help.